# Why does System.Type.GetHashCode return the same value for all instances and types?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

The following code produces the output of 46104728:

```
using System;

namespace TestApplication
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Type type = typeof(string);
            Console.WriteLine(type.GetHashCode());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But so does this:

```
using System;

namespace TestApplication
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Type type = typeof(Program);
            Console.WriteLine(type.GetHashCode());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
 }
```

Yet on http://ideone.com it produces varying results for each type. This issue has been reproduced on more than one system now. I'm using .NET 4.0 right now.

Comment: +1, Interesting. While they dont match for me, the results seem to sometimes not consistent.

Comment: I do not share the same behavior on .Net 4.0, nor 3.5, nor 2.0, when you look at their hash codes at the same time. It appears that Type hashcodes start at one value and are based on the order of their use or appearance (although of that I'm not sure).

Comment: @sixlettervariables are you in debug or release mode and are you testing it with a debugger (VS) attached?

Comment: Consider reading [GetHashCode guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Irrelevant, we are dealing with internally-implemented hashcodes.

Comment: @leppie, not irrelevant, Eric says very clearly what the use case of GetHashCode is and that you shouldn't rely on an implementation across time and systems, see rule 3.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You've run into what you believe to be a problem, however, if you were to look at their hash codes *in the same execution* you'll find that they're not identical but instead rely on their order of usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:08X}", typeof(string), typeof(string).GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:08X}", typeof(Program), typeof(Program).GetHashCode());
// System.String 02BF8098
// Program 00BB8560
```

If I run that same program again, swapping their order:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:08X}", typeof(Program), typeof(Program).GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:08X}", typeof(string), typeof(string).GetHashCode());
// Program 02BF8098
// System.String 00BB8560
```

This is a non-issue at runtime as the returned values do not violate the rules for implementing `Object.GetHashCode`.

But, as you noted this behavior seems curious!

I delved into the source and found the implementation of `Type.GetHashCode` is foisted off onto `MemberInfo.GetHashCode`, which is again foisted off onto `Object.GetHashCode` which calls `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this)`.

It is at this point that the trail goes cold, however, my assumption is the inner workings of that method creates a new value, mapped per instance, based on the order of calls.

I tested this hypothesis by running the same code above with two instances of `Program` (after adding a property to identify them):

```
var b = new Program() { Name = "B" };
var a = new Program() { Name = "A" };
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:08X}", a.Name, a.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:08X}", b.Name, b.GetHashCode());
// A 02BF8098
// B 00BB8560
```

Thus, for classes which do not explicitly override `Object.GetHashCode`, instances will be assigned a seemingly predictable hash value based on the order in which they call `GetHashCode`.

---

*Update:* I went and looked at how Rotor/Shared Source CLI handles this situation, and I learned that the default implementation calculates and stores a hash code in the sync block for the object instance, thus ensuring the hash code is generated only once. The default computation for this hash code is trivial, and uses a per-thread seed (wrapping is mine):

```
// ./sscli20/clr/src/vm/threads.h(938)
// Every thread has its own generator for hash codes so that we
// won't get into a situation where two threads consistently give
// out the same hash codes.
// Choice of multiplier guarantees period of 2**32
// - see Knuth Vol 2 p16 (3.2.1.2 Theorem A).
```

So if the actual CLR follows this implementation it would seem any differences seen in hash code values for objects are based on the AppDomain and Managed Thread which created the instance.

Comment: What makes me curious mostly is why it had the value I originally placed for my same assembly run on two different machines. They're in two distinct states so there must be something very deterministic about it as you mentioned in the other comments.

Comment: @JNZ: eh, I'll bet the Framework has some seed value hardcoded, so it is always the same across your machines.

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense because then it would be the same on two different systems with .NET 4.0. It's different on two distinct machines which are configured differently but running .NET 4.0 currently, they're not even both mine.

Comment: Why not, what if the algorithm was simply `hash = hash + counter` and `hash = seed` as the initialization?

Comment: Most hash algorithms start with a well known, hard coded, non-random seed. Read up on [Bob Jenkins' hash algorithms](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html), he has lots of nice details inside. I'm certain it starts from a fixed seed because `46104728` is `0x02BF8098`, coincidentally the same hash code I get.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5121/discussion-between-jnz-and-sixlettervariables)

Answer (score 10):

Program (.NET 4, AnyCPU):

```
var st = typeof(string);
var pt = typeof(Program);
Console.WriteLine(st.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(pt.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).GetHashCode());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Run 1:

```
33156464
15645912
33156464
15645912
```

Run 2-6:

```
45653674
41149443
45653674
41149443
```

Run 7:

```
46104728
12289376
46104728
12289376
```

Run 8:

```
37121646
45592480
37121646
45592480
```

While I can understand the randomness **as long as the hashcode is consistent during the program lifetime**, it bothers me that it is not always random.

Comment: Interesting work really. On my system, it appears the first call to `System.Type.GetHashCode` is always the same between runs. However, subsequent calls make it different for different `Type` instances (on different types of course). I believe it's seeded somehow and produces a biased result.

Comment: @JNZ: the answer is `Type` doesn't override `GetHashCode` and thus uses the default implementation, which assigns them in a pseudo-deterministic fashion based on the order in which `GetHashCode` is called.

Comment: @JNZ: You should give the other answerer the 'tick'. Mine was just my own observations without trying to answer the question :)

Comment: That was a misplaced click honestly. I didn't mean for anyone to get it yet heh. Simply +1'd you for the information that lead me on an investigative hunt.

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprising result, with a relatively simple explanation.

The class `Type` uses the default implementations for `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `object`. Specifically, `Type` instances are equal when they are the same instance (i.e. at the same memory address). Similarly, when the objects are the same instance, their hash codes will be equal.

`typeof` uses caching, so for a given type, it will always return the same instance, which mimics the behavior of member equality, but it is not:

```
object.ReferenceEquals(typeof(string), typeof(string)) == true
```

As for the original question, this result can hold for any reference type that does not override `GetHashCode`.  There is no reason why the output of `GetHashCode` should be random, it needs only be different for objects at different memory addresses (and well distributed in the output range).  If memory addresses are assigned sequentially from the same starting point, the sequence of hash codes generated from those objects will also be the same.

I should add that I do not know the actual base implementation of `GetHashCode`, I am merely theorizing that it would be sensible for it to derive from the memory address of the reference type.

Answer (score -1):

In response to Eric Ouellet's answer, I'll not even comment on the incorrect syntax (oops, guess just I did), but that information is factually inaccurate.

Results from the C# interactive console in Visual Studio prove GetHashCode() works as expected on generic types.

Witness:

```
> typeof(List<int>).GetHashCode()
42194754
> typeof(List<string>).GetHashCode()
39774547
> typeof(Stack<string>).GetHashCode()
59652943
> typeof(Stack<int>).GetHashCode()
5669220
```