# Lambda expression execution

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

When the DoTranslation method is run, the output is the same hash code for
all of the TranslatedObjects.  Why is this happening as opposed to having a new List for each TranslatedObject?

```
public class TranslatedObject
{
    public static Expression<Func<OriginalObject, TranslatedObject>> ObjectTranslator = o => new TranslatedObject
    {
        id = o.id
        translatedList = new List<String>()
    };

    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<String> translatedList { get; set; }
}


public class Translator
{
    public void DoTranslation()
    {
        //3 objects returned with ids 1, 2, and 3 respectively
        IQueryable<OriginalObject> originalObjects = dataContext.OriginalObjects.Where(o => o.id == 1 || o.id == 2 || o.id == 3);

        var translatedObjects = originalObjects.Select(TranslatedObject.ObjectTranslator).ToArray();

        foreach(TranslatedObject translated in translatedObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(translated.translatedList.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Changed service call to the following linq-to-sql call: dataContext.OriginalObjects.Where(o => o.id == 1 || o.id == 2 || o.id == 3).

Comment: What do the translated lists contain? All of them are equal?

Comment: I get the expected result (different HashCodes): http://ideone.com/nWfjap

Comment: It returns different results for me too. Tried all versions of .NET and Debug/Release.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178115/

Comment: Every translatedList is just an empty List<string> right. So what is wrong with them returning the same hashcode?? It doesn't break any definitions.....and in fact looks pretty natural - they're 3 equivalent(not equal) collections of the same type..... What makes you think it's the same list being re-used?? 2 objects can have same hashcode without being equal.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I ran the code snippet from w0lf and it did write different hash codes.  The service.GetOriginalObjects() call is actually a linq-to-sql query that returns an IQueryable.  Something along the lines of dataContext.OriginalObjects.Where(o => o.id == 1 || o.id == 2 || o.id == 3).  Do you see any reason why this would cause the hash codes to be the same?

Comment: I just tried your code, where I made service a Linq-to-SQL DataContext. And yes, I can confirm that all translatedList in different TranslatedObjects are same instance of that one list. So this is problem related to that and you should update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Vivek: Constructing two distinct `List<T>` objects and leaving them empty will produce different hash codes since `List<T>` doesn't care about the contents, it only does reference equality.

Comment: @Lasse: That may be so. The point i was raising was that the 2 lists having the same hash code is not wrong.... it's very much within the definition, and concluding that 2 objects are the same if their hashes match is what's wrong. It just so happens List<T> just uses the default object.GetHashCode(afaik) which generates a fresh int for every new object.